# Python Flask working with wraps

Tags: python, flask, decorator, python-decorators

Trying to setup a login page with Python and Flask and getting an Error:
*(line 33 is the with `@login_required`)*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "routes.py", line 33, in <module>
    @login_required
  File "/home/pi/FlaskTutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1013, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "/home/pi/FlaskTutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 62, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/FlaskTutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 942, in add_url_rule
    endpoint = _endpoint_from_view_func(view_func)
  File "/home/pi/FlaskTutorial/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 60, in _endpoint_from_view_func
    assert view_func is not None, 'expected view func if endpoint ' \
AssertionError: expected view func if endpoint is not provided.
```

Here is the code I am using, I can't seem to find the problem... Any ideas?

```
from flask import *
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'secret key' #Use a random key generator

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome.html')

def login_required(test):
    @wraps(test)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return test(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first.')
            return redirect(url_for('log'))
        return wrap

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect (url_for('log'))

@app.route('/hello')
@login_required
def hello():
    return render_template('hello.html')

@app.route('/log', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def log():
    error = None
    if request.method =='POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invaled Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect(url_for('hello'))
    return render_template('log.html', error=error)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You indented the `return wrap` line too far, now your decorator returns a `None` value. Unindent the last line:

```
def login_required(test):
    @wraps(test)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return test(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to login first.')
            return redirect(url_for('log'))
    return wrap
```

The exception points to the `@login_required` line because the *next* decorator, `@app.route('/hello')` throws the exception as it is applied to the output of `@login_required`. The `AssertionError` exception is thrown explicitly because the route decorator was passed a `None` value for the function.

Comment: Thanks, You stare at it so long you can't see the forest through the woods...Thanks again

Comment: Thanks happened to run into same issue.